# Express.js post request not handling route

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, express, http-post

This is the folder structure:

[image]

I'm trying to make my python script get input from my html file and give it's output displayed by the html

Here is the html script in jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit_SF").click(function () {
            var userChoice = $("#score_function").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/runSF",
                method: "POST",
                data: { choice: userChoice },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tableData").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my `app.js` file:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Define route var
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var fsRouter = require('./routes/fs');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Define route
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/fs', fsRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post("/runSF", (req, res) => {
  const userChoice = req.body.choice;
  console.log("Received POST request with user choice:", userChoice);

  // Run the Python script with the user's choice as an argument
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['SFscript.py', userChoice]);

  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // Send the Python script's output back to the client
    const outputData = data.toString();
    console.log("Python script output:", outputData); // Log script output
    res.send(outputData);
  });

  pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error("Error executing Python script:", data); // Log script errors
  });
});
```

The browser console shows this when I click the html button:

```
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2     POST http://localhost:3000/runFS 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ fs:50
dispatch @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
```

I fell this is something really easy to fix, but my knowledge in node.js is insufficient.

I don't know what to try, shouldn't this `app.post("/runFS", (req, res) => {});` be enough to configure the route?

Feel free to request any other files that I haven't shown. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `app.post("/runSF"` route above your route that handles and calls your `next(createError(404));`. So this:

```
app.post("/runSF", (req, res) => {
   const userChoice = req.body.choice; 
   //...Rest of code
   //...
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
```

It looks like you are creating the 404 before your `app.post("/runSF"`can be reached.

The following lines are also redundant:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //< Same as express.urlencoded
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

That's because you already called them near the top of you file here:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something trivial hahaha
thank you very much